Performance when ingesting into AWS Sagemaker feature stores using feature processors
I'm trying to use the Sagemaker Feature Store Feature Processor SDK to ingest data into an OfflineStore and OnlineStore.
Without the OnlineStore included in the config, and with the feature group's table_format set to ICEBERG (important otherwise also very slow!), the 1M row data set loads in ~13 minutes. The s3 bucket for the offline store has one file per day as expected.
However, when I include OnlineStore in the feature processor target stores config, the ingestion becomes incredibly slow, and I see many files per day in the s3 bucket for the offline store:
2024-05-16 17:25:40       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/dfkchwkp/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T164259Z_xuEYFSbUERrnKwQx.parquet
2024-05-16 17:21:10       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/iyzled4v/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T065739Z_yoFAGbgxIFClXSFy.parquet
2024-05-16 17:25:40       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/qvvzi6tz/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T180708Z_icsZiEfeGETlPgFl.parquet
2024-05-16 17:21:09       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/rmmlxmbw/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T181622Z_uyyeaMQWysmxzTez.parquet
2024-05-16 17:21:10       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/yaiznhwv/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T102844Z_kVUEXnFqcRCdaeGB.parquet
2024-05-16 17:25:40       4711 feature-store/sandbox/redacted/sagemaker/eu-west-1/offline-store/crb-1715868548/data/yzk3hxbn/created_at_trunc=2023-05-07/20230507T161916Z_eFLMXfmhPkorCPyJ.parquet

Here is the code I'm using:
@feature_processor(
    inputs=[SnowflakeDataSource(query, sf_options, secret)], 
    # snowflake data source implemented using code in custom data sources doc
    output=CRB_FG_ARN,
    target_stores=["OfflineStore", "OnlineStore"],
    spark_config={"spark.jars.packages": "net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.12.0-spark_3.3"}
)
def transform(input_df):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp

    transformed_df = (
        input_df.select([col(x).alias(x.lower()) for x in input_df.columns])
        .withColumn("created_at", date_format("created_at", ISO_8601_TIMESTAMP))
    )

    # this print statement is shown within seconds implying latency is not with snowflake query
    print(f"dataframe shape: {(transformed_df.count(), len(transformed_df.columns))}")

    return transformed_df

transform()

Questions:

Is it the expected behaviour that writing to the OnlineStore with a feature processor will create many files per day?
Is this the best way to ingest features to the OfflineStore and the OnlineStore, or should I first ingest to the OfflineStore, then promote to the OnlineStore as described in this "common use case" doc? I have tried this, but it too appears to run very slowly.

Meta question:

Does anyone know of a good Slack/Discord for discussing Sagemaker?


Have you considered to run OPTIMIZE and VACUUM on the underlying Iceberg tables? See this blog post for more infomation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/speed-ml-development-using-sagemaker-feature-store-and-apache-iceberg-offline-store-compaction/

I haven't looked into that yet, thanks for the tip. Considering this is just the initial load of data, I wouldn't have expected such operations would be necessary though.
